# Transform scaled element spacing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Simply I have build a slider using swiper.js (vertical) library and the problem is that it always center a slider tile that is red in background. Because of the transform scale property the height of it increases and the margin is also not working as expected. The center slider is like overlaying into the previous and next slides.

Please run the below code to understand me more.

```css
.slider {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.slider.active {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);1
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div class="slider previous">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div class="slider active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div class="slider next">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please further explain the desired behavior.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Please take a look at the active slider you will found that the margin not working with it as I expected and I understand that this is happening because of the transform but I don't have any solutions.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi The center slider is like moving/overlaying into previous and next slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want your slider elements to not exceed the parent `<div>` when they are scaled. May I suggest achieving the this with four ideas:

1. Using CSS Flexbox to organize your sliders and center them vertically and horizontally in an easy manner.
2. Adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to the style of your sliders to make sure borders are accounted for when calculating the size of a slider.
3. Assigning a percentage width to the slider based on the scaling you want to apply to them so that they do not exceed the size of the parent when scaled. I would suggest taking the floor value of (1 / scaling factor). In this case: `floor(1 / 1.1) = 90`.
4. Only scale up on the X axis to avoid overlap of slider elements.

Here is what it would look like (I added a parent border to make it easier to see):

```css
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider {
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider.active {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="slider">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="slider previous">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="slider active">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="slider next">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You still don't understand me and I don't know why :D Please take a look here https://b.imge.to/2019/10/03/vE8Qai.png you will found that the red slider overlaying into the other slides right? Why? Because of the transform scale effect okay what I need to achieve? making it not overlaying into the other slides.

Comment: Ah now I see, would it still solve your problem to scale the only on the x axis, and leave the y axis as is, the overlapping will go away. I updated my answer.